# How to add new array to previous array?

Tags: python

I have an image that I do some processing and want to add the results to previous array I had like this:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math
from scipy import misc
from PIL import Image

#load image
img = Image.open("X.png")

#my functions being defined here
def somefunctions():
return some_results

A = []

for i in range(0,13):
   A.append([])
   for j in range(0,13):

         # DO SOME PROCESSING


         # Compute weights
         Ckr = Ckr_sg(some input)
         # Ckr is a 5*5 array

         # add new Ckr to the array A
         print type(A)
         A[i].append(A.extend(Ckr))
```

However, my problem is that A is considered list type and each time None value is also added too as:

```
 <type 'list'>
 [[None], array([ 0.05910575,  0.10687793,  0.13533528,  0.10687793,   0.05910575]), array([ 0.10687793,  0.24311673,  0.36787944,  0.24311673,  0.10687793]), array([ 0.13533528,  0.36787944,  1.        ,  0.36787944,  0.13533528]), array([ 0.10687793,  0.24311673,  0.36787944,  0.24311673,  0.10687793]), array([ 0.05910575,  0.10687793,  0.13533528,  0.10687793,  0.05910575])]
 <type 'list'>
[[None, None], array([ 0.05910575,  0.10687793,  0.13533528,  0.10687793,  0.05910575]), array([ 0.10687793,  0.24311673,  0.36787944,  0.24311673,  0.10687793]), array([ 0.13533528,  0.36787944,  1.        ,  0.36787944,  0.13533528]), array([ 0.10687793,  0.24311673,  0.36787944,  0.24311673,  0.10687793]), array([ 0.05910575,  0.10687793,  0.13533528,  0.10687793,  0.05910575]), array([ 0.05910575,  0.10687793,  0.13533528,  0.10687793,  0.05910575]), array([ 0.10687793,  0.24311673,  0.36787944,  0.24311673,  0.10687793]), array([ 0.13533528,  0.36787944,  1.        ,  0.36787944,  0.13533528]), array([ 0.10687793,  0.24311673,  0.36787944,  0.24311673,  0.10687793]), array([ 0.05910575,  0.10687793,  0.13533528,  0.10687793,  0.05910575])]
<type 'list'>
 [[None, None, None], array([ 0.05910575,  0.10687793,  0.13533528,  0.10687793,  0.05910575]), array([ 0.10687793,  0.24311673,  0.36787944,  0.24311673,  0.10687793]), array([ 0.13533528,  0.36787944,  1.        ,  0.36787944,  0.13533528]), array([ 0.10687793,  0.24311673,  0.36787944,  0.24311673,  0.10687793]), array([ 0.05910575,  0.10687793,  0.13533528,  0.10687793,  0.05910575]), array([ 0.05910575,  0.10687793,  0.13533528,  0.10687793,  0.05910575]), array([ 0.10687793,  0.24311673,  0.36787944,  0.24311673,  0.10687793]), array([ 0.13533528,  0.36787944,  1.        ,  0.36787944,  0.13533528]), array([ 0.10687793,  0.24311673,  0.36787944,  0.24311673,  0.10687793]), array([ 0.05910575,  0.10687793,  0.13533528,  0.10687793,  0.05910575]), array([ 0.05910575,  0.10687793,  0.13533528,  0.10687793,  0.05910575]), array([ 0.10687793,  0.24311673,  0.36787944,  0.24311673,  0.10687793]), array([ 0.13533528,  0.36787944,  1.        ,  0.36787944,  0.13533528]), array([ 0.10687793,  0.24311673,  0.36787944,  0.24311673,  0.10687793]), array([ 0.05910575,  0.10687793,  0.13533528,  0.10687793,  0.05910575])]
 <type 'list'>
 [[None, None, None, None], array([ 0.05910575,  0.10687793,  0.13533528,  0.10687793,  0.05910575]), array([ 0.10687793,  0.24311673,  0.36787944,  0.24311673,  0.10687793]), array([ 0.13533528,  0.36787944,  1.        ,  0.36787944,  0.13533528]), array([ 0.10687793,  0.24311673,  0.36787944,  0.24311673,  0.10687793]), array([ 0.05910575,  0.10687793,  0.13533528,  0.10687793,  0.05910575]), array([ 0.05910575,  0.10687793,  0.13533528,  0.10687793,  0.05910575]), array([ 0.10687793,  0.24311673,  0.36787944,  0.24311673,  0.10687793]), array([ 0.13533528,  0.36787944,  1.        ,  0.36787944,  0.13533528]), array([ 0.10687793,  0.24311673,  0.36787944,  0.24311673,  0.10687793]), array([ 0.05910575,  0.10687793,  0.13533528,  0.10687793,  0.05910575]), array([ 0.05910575,  0.10687793,  0.13533528,  0.10687793,  0.05910575]), array([ 0.10687793,  0.24311673,  0.36787944,  0.24311673,  0.10687793]), array([ 0.13533528,  0.36787944,  1.        ,  0.36787944,  0.13533528]), array([ 0.10687793,  0.24311673,  0.36787944,  0.24311673,  0.10687793]), array([ 0.05910575,  0.10687793,  0.13533528,  0.10687793,  0.05910575]), array([ 0.05910575,  0.10687793,  0.13533528,  0.10687793,  0.05910575]), array([ 0.10687793,  0.24311673,  0.36787944,  0.24311673,  0.10687793]), array([ 0.13533528,  0.36787944,  1.        ,  0.36787944,  0.13533528]), array([ 0.10687793,  0.24311673,  0.36787944,  0.24311673,  0.10687793]), array([ 0.05910575,  0.10687793,  0.13533528,  0.10687793,  0.05910575])]
```

but I do like like these None values. What should I do?

Comment: **correction >>** I do not like the None values.

Comment: I think you can do A.extend(B) and it will combine A and B

Comment: No this way has no answers..when j = 0, the value of A is "None" and the type is "list", when j=1; the type changes to "NoneType" and so **extend** does not work!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "add" to array? You want to insert the result? You want to add the elements?

Comment: speaking in matrix view: for example I have an empty matrix `A = []`. in `j= 1`, I add a new matrix `[1 2 ; 3 4]`. so `A = [1 2 ; 3 4]`. now for `j = 2`, I add another matrix `[1 9; 7 8]`. so `A = [1 2 1 9; 3 4 7 8]`..this is in MATLAB matrix form. sorry to explain in that format since visualizing that in matrix is easier for me than array in python.

Comment: as I searched I can do it with `hstack`. But still my problem is I should define a zero array and then I add the new arrays which creates 0 values at the begining for me. if better ways it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using `numpy`, I recommend you pre-allocate a numpy array and then fill it out.  For example

```
A=np.empty((13, 13), dtype=np.int32)
for j in range(0,13):
    for j in range(0,13):
        A[j, k] = .... whatever you want ...
```

This way is probably more efficient that what you are doing, and more importantly it makes data type/array shape handling simpler -- the whole 13x13 array is made for you on the first line and then you just have to worry about what you put in it.

`np.empty` creates an array of uninitialised values. You can also use `np.zeros` and `np.ones`.

Comment: the new array I want to add is a 5*5 array..not a single value!

Comment: If it is always going to be 5x5, then you can pre-allocate a 13x13x5x5 array.  But you are right, that if there are going to be heterogenous objects in your big array, then sticking Python lists would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Try verifying the values before you append them to your list:

```
if not(None in Ckr): 
    # Append it
```

or alternatively:

```
Ckr = [item for item in Ckr if not(item is None)]
```